# How can i insert vertical space between the rows(input text boxes and Labels)?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learning</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        ...

<h1>Testing</h1>
<span class="error">* Required</span>
<form name="SignUp"  method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label><input id="NAME" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
     </div> 

    <div>     
        <label>Email:</label><input id="EMAIL"  type="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label></label><input type="submit" value="Send" >
    </div>
</fieldset>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:#b0c4de;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:15px;
}
p {color:blue;}
.error {color: #FF0000;}
label { 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right:30px;  //How far the label element and input box
    margin-top:100px;
 }
fieldset{
    //border:none;
    padding:15px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

The Name: and input box are on one line and the next line is just touching it.

how do i put them [apart](http://jsbin.com/igacu4/10/edit#/igacu4/11/edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `line-height` to the `div` like below:

```
div{
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/XyubK/)

**Note:** Here, I have applied the property for `div` tag in general as it is only an example. In actual case, you might want to add a `class` for the `div` tags within the `fieldset` and apply the `line-height` only for that class. Doing it that way will make sure other `div` tags in the page aren't affected.

Answer (score 1):

without getting too complicated, something simple as the following will produce the desired results

```
#NAME, #EMAIL, input[type=submit] {
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

this gives your input fields a small space above so that they are spread out.

Note: I have used specific selectors to apply these values to the fields in your example only.

Answer (score 1):

add below css to your code

```
div{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

you can change margin as your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to implement this.
The simplest way is simply to insert a < BR > between label  and the input tag.

A second way is to use a table and place the input in the cell below.

An alternative way is to use for example divs and place the label in one div and the input in another and use css techniques like float etc. This has the advantage of controlling everything via css.